# what is the json format for delta<TEntity> in MVC Data v4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have a controller:

```
public class PostsController : ODataController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Post(Post post) {}
    public IHttpActionResult Put([FromODataUri] int key, Delta<Post> patch) {}
}
```

The `Post` entity has only 2 fields: an `int Id` and a `string Content`. 
The following `json`message is working fine with POST action:

```
{
  content: "dasdasd678678678"
}
```

However, the PUT action is rejecting the request and returning a 400 error:

```
{
  "error":{
    "code":"","message":"The request is invalid.","innererror":{
      "message":"The parameters dictionary contains an invalid entry for parameter 'patch' for method 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult Put(Int32, System.Web.OData.Delta`1[Post])' in 'NWeb.Controllers.API.PostsController'. The dictionary contains a value of type 'Entity.Post', but the parameter requires a value of type 'System.Web.OData.Delta`1[Entity.Post]'.","type":"","stacktrace":""
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PUT action should work like below

`public IHttpActionResult Put([FromODataUri] int key, Post post) {}`

And the `delta<Entity>` should work with PATCH like this

`public IHttpActionResult Patch([FromODataUri] int key, Delta<Post> post)`

PUT and PATCH are both for updating entities, but PUT need the full payload for the updated entity and PATCH only need the delta information.

Comment: I ended up using PATCH instead of PUT. Also, I had several issues with deserializing delta<T> when my T type contains DbGeography properties. But that's another issue and I had solved that by implementing a Custom Media Type Formatter.